# Problem with dynamic pages offline in React

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I've got a problem accessing dynamic pages offline.

My website got a landing pages which loads a objects and its children. All these data is saved to the indexDB. If I press on any children, I redirect to a dynamic page based on the childs ID.

If I decide to go offline and refresh the browser, the page won't load. If I however when being offline refresh on the "parent" page which isn't a dynamic page I do get the content and can click on the children to redirect correctly.

I do think the reason for this is that I am using history.push in react which do not work as a redirect and therefor it does not save the dynamic url to the cache. Would like to keep using push instead since I do not want server side rendering when using React.

Not sure how to solve this. How can I access the dynamic pages offline when I am not saving them dynamically? Can I in the service worker somehow intercept and access the page since all data is already saved?

Edit:
Found a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057044/how-to-add-dynamic-routes-to-cache-when-installing-service-worker) - with 0 answers.

Comment: I'm not a React specialist but I understand that you do not need a router with React. In that case, you can let the service worker handle the navigation request and serve a dynamically built page